# Как получить значение атрибута width в img?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я пытаюсь сравнить значение атрибута ширины у картинки, но получаю в консоль только undefined. Как мне получить значение атрибута ширины у картинки ?

```
var $img = $('.img-pr-medium');
$img.load(function(){
    var width = img.clientWidth;
    if(width === 1200) {
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

Comment: точно ли у картинки с таким классом есть данный атрибут?

Comment: слишком мало информации, загрузился ли элемент с картинкой на момент проверки? есть ли атрибут ширины у этого элемента?

Comment: атрибут ширины у элемента точно есть

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function testFunction() {
let image = $('.test-image');
let width = image.innerWidth();
if (width === 100) {
  image.innerWidth(1000);
}
}
```

```css
.test-image {
  width: 100px;
  heigth: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class='test-image' src='http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/leto_derevo_nebo_peyzazh_dom_derevya_domik_priroda_3000x2000.jpg'>
<br>
<button onclick="testFunction()">Нажми меня для увеличения</button>
```

Comment: это увы не помогло.

Comment: @Kek поправил, сейчас работает

Comment: Борический, спасибо за ответ. Но у меня другая ситуация - мне нужно достучаться  именно до атрибута ширины в самом теге и измерять только его ширину.

Comment: @Kek поменял в условии) То есть делаете image.innerWidth(1000) например и вашему элементу поставит нужную ширину